# How can I test the rendering of an element using the date pipe in Angular 2?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

I can't seem to test a component that uses a Date pipe in Angular 2 (using Karma through PhantomJS).  When I try, I get **ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Intl**

Here's my entire spec file:

```js
import { provide, PLATFORM_PIPES } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { addProviders, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { Post, PostComponent, PostHtmlComponent } from './';
import { usingComponentFixture } from '../../test-helpers';

describe('Component: Post', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    provide(PLATFORM_PIPES, {useValue: DatePipe, multi: true });
    addProviders([PostComponent, PostHtmlComponent, ]);
  });

  it('should render an h1 tag with text matching the post title', 
    usingComponentFixture(PostComponent, fixture => {
        let component = <PostComponent>fixture.componentInstance;
        let element = fixture.nativeElement;

        component.post = <Post>{ title: 'Hello', publishedOn: new Date('8/5/2016') };
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(element.querySelector('.blog-post-header h1').innerText).toBe('Hello');
    })
  );
});
```

And this is the component template:

```html
 <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-6">
   <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
   <p class="lead">{{post.publishedOn | date:'fullDate'}}</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 7):

I was able to resolve this issue.  Here's what I had to do:

1. npm install karma-intl-shim --save-dev
2. Add 'intl-shim' to the frameworks collection in karma.conf.js
3. Add the following to karma-test-shim.js (this is referenced in the files collection of karma.conf.js)

   ```
   require('karma-intl-shim');
   require('./en-us.js'); // copied from https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/blob/master/locale-data/json/en-US.json
   Intl.__addLocaleData(enUsLocaleData);
   ```

Comment: ```import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en-us.js';``` can be used instead of copying from somewhere else.

Comment: Is there advise for the same issue but with Angular JS 1?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of mocking the DatePipe, you can use the `transform` method of DatePipe in typescript which is equivalent to the | operator in the HTML file

```js
import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';

let pipe = new DatePipe('en');

expect(page.myDate.nativeElement.innerHTML).toBe(pipe.transform(model.date, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
```

Comment: Typically it is best to provide some explanation along with a coding solution.

Comment: How did you get around       ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Intl in http://localhost:9877karma-test-shim.js (line 20014)?

Answer (score 5):

For tests I mock date pipe:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'date',
    pure: false // required to update the value when the promise is resolved
})

export class MockedDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    name: string = 'date';

    transform(query: string, ...args: any[]): any {
        return query;
    }
}
```

Then when I configure testing module I inject it into declaration:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule( {
    providers: [
        SelectionDispatcher,
        { provide: MyService, useClass: MockedMyServiceService }
    ],
    declarations: [ MyComponent, MockedTranslatePipe, MockedDatePipe ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea. I've been messing around with the TranslationModule, but couldn't get it to work. The test isn't about translation; but the translation pipe was getting in the way.

Comment: Did you still have to add a polyfill for dates?  Can't figure out how to get around ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Intl.

Comment: Nice. I use this to circumvent localization issues with snapshot tests between different locations :)

Answer (score 5):

that's what worked for me:

```js
import {DatePipe} from "@angular/common";
...
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  ...
  providers: [DatePipe]
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

That worked for me:

```
import { DatePipe, registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeDe from '@angular/common/locales/de';

registerLocaleData(localeDe);

//..
describe('My Test', () => {

let pipe = new DatePipe('de-DE');
    it('My Test-Case', () => {
        expect(page.myDate.nativeElement.innerHTML).toBe(pipe.transform(model.date);
    });
});
```

You must set the right locale.

That is a snippet from a Cypress-Test.

Answer (score -1):

Expanding on other answers on here I was using the DatePipe in my component to produce a payload. I had the following setup.

Return the transform method on DatePipe in the mock, matching parameters used by the component i.e. ('YY'). Otherwise we will just get undefined as the value when testing.

.spec file

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
.....
const mockDatePipe = {
  transform: jest.fn((val) => new DatePipe('en').transform(val, 'YY')),
};
.....
beforeEach(() => {
  component = new TestComponent(
    (mockDatePipe as unknown) as DatePipe,
    .....
  );
});

it('should return correct payload', () => {
  expect(component.getPayload(new Date('2022-02-02')).toEqual(
    {
      purchaseYear: '22',
    }
}
```

.ts file

```
public getPayload(date: new Date(), .....){
   return {
      purchaseYear: this.datePipe.transform(date, 'YY')
   };
);
```